# Usage of \newcommand

Tags: math-mode

I'm not sure why this command isn't working out for me.

```
\newcommand{\sprod}[2]{\left|\left< {#1} \right| \! \left. \! {#2} \right>\right|}
```

When I have `$\sprod{\psi,\phi}$` in the body, my compiler says "Missing } Inserted"

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: `\sprod{\psi}{\phi}`

Comment: Is there any way of defining the command so that it can be given as above?

Comment: @ASimmons Oh you don't wanna go there ...

Comment: There are ways to define your special syntax (e.g. with `latex3` and a `clist`). But I suggest to use the regular syntax with braces for each argument.

Comment: Also, instead of `\right| \! \left. \!` in the macro's definition, do use `\,\middle\vert\,`.

Comment: This is apparently related to `bra` and `kets` of Quantum Mechanics -- there is at least one package that provides such means, but I can't remember the name :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `braket`, perhaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're defining `\sprod` with two arguments, but you're supplying just one; the call should be `\sprod{\psi}{\phi}`.

However, with some more work, we can define a better setup, with the syntax with a comma.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\iprod}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\splitprod{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitprod}{>{\SplitArgument{1},}{m}}{\dosplitprod#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dosplitprod}{mm}{%
  #1\nonscript\;\delimsize|\nonscript\;#2%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sprod}{sO{}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\abs*{\iprod*{#3}}}
    {\abs[#2]{\iprod[#2]{#3}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\sprod{\psi,\phi}+\sprod[\big]{\psi,\phi}+\sprod*{\frac{\psi}{2},\phi}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro `\iprod` does the same, but without the outer bars.

The optional argument to `\sprod` and `\iprod` tells the size; with `\sprod*` you get automatic sizing. It's better this way than filling up your macros with `\left` and `\right` that quite rarely do what you expect.

---

Some explanation are in order. Let's examine the `\iprod` macro; with a syntax such as `\iprod{a}{b}`, it would be simpler:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\iprod}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{%
  #1\nonscript\;\delimsize|\nonscript\;#2%
}
```

(see the documentation of `mathtools`). But as you want `\iprod{a,b}` I used `xparse` for splitting the argument at the comma, passing it to the macro `\dosplitprod` that provides the `#1\nonscript\;\delimsize|\nonscript\;#2` bit.

For `\sprod` I simply nest `\iprod` inside `\abs`, passing both macros the same arguments.